# Bash: why does comparison precedence matter with wildcards?

Tags: bash, shell

Is the `==` functioning like an `IN` operator when the test string contains wildcards? It's very magical...

example1:

```
string='My long string';
if [[ $string == *"My long"* ]]; then   echo "It's there!"; fi
```

output:

```
It's There
```

example2:

```
if [[ *"My long"* == $string ]]; then   echo "It's there!"; fi
```

No output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's how [`[[ ]]`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Conditional-Constructs) was designed to work. It's in the manual:

> When the ‘==’ and ‘!=’ operators are used, the string to the right of the operator is considered a pattern and matched according to the rules described below in Pattern Matching.

Comment: I'm going to mark this as correct - But I will note that this behaviour is bizarre and there is no explanation for the logic behind it.

Answer (score 2):

Glob pattern only works on right hand side of comparison that's why

```
if [[ *"My long"* == $string ]]; then   echo "It's there!"; fi
```

will fail.

Even this won't work:

```
[[ *"My long"* == "My long" ]] && echo "It's there!"
```

But this will work:

```
[[ "My long" == *"My long"* ]] && echo "It's there!"
It's there!
```

---

If you are asking how this is working:

```
string='My long string';
if [[ $string == *"My long"* ]]; then   echo "It's there!"; fi
```

Then it is working due to use of `glob` matching on your RHS pattern that uses `*`

Which means match anything before and after literal text `"My long"` and since your input does contain `"My long"` hence match succeeds.

Comment: Yes, i got that part, but what's the logic behind this magic?

Comment: The part where `right` and `left` sides of a `==` operator are non-congruent, which defies normal logic.

Comment: Ok check my updated answer and let me know if you have more questions.

Comment: Yeah, I'm wondering whether the guy who thought it was a good idea to design `equal` as implementation which is quite literally `not-equal` for no apparent reason was using a psychedelic (which one?) or smoking crack, or perhaps both.

Comment: Yes even `[[ "My long" = *"My long"* ]] && echo "It's there!"` will work. It is due to use of glob matching in BASH using `[[...]]`